# Can I move a save-game from Red Dead Redemption with DLC to a vanilla copy of RDR?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

Last year for Christmas I got Red Dead Redemption GOTY for the PS3, which includes all the DLC.I then gave it to a friend so he can play it. A few days ago my Dad gave me his vanilla version of Red Dead Redemption (without any DLC). **Is it possible to move the saved files from my GOTY edition** (with the DLC) **and move it to my vanilla version of the game** (without the DLC)**?**

Comment: I'm guessing, but usually any items that you may have received from the extra content (ie. Missions/rewards, etc.) will be missing. Apart from that - Your save file should load fine.

Comment: I would say no, since some of the DLC directly affects the save game itself, which could lead to many errors when playing with the NON-DLC version.

Comment: @Kevvygomez3, why don't you try with another save, then see if THAT works?

Comment: Isn't it that the DLC is stored on the PS3 itself?